# Binary search with C

Tags: c, algorithm, search, runtime-error, binary-search

I understand the concept pretty throughly oh how the binary search works and what needs to take place, yet when attempting to implement with C, the search has not yet once been successful. I could really use a well given explanation of where my error exists and why it is error prone as well as the proper way to re-write it. This is not a homework assignment I would like to point out but just a topic that has to be applied throughly for me to pass Computer Science II. Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {       
    int array[11] = {11,24,47, 57,58,59,89,94,102,150,250};

    int n = sizeof(array)/4;             
    int key;                         

    int topIndex = n-1;        
    int bottomIndex = 0;        

    int middleIndex = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2; 

    printf("%d is the initial middle index position which contains the integer %d\n\n", middleIndex, array[middleIndex]);

    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("%d was read in, i will now search for the number\n\n", key);

    while(bottomIndex<=topIndex)
    {
        if(key==array[middleIndex])
        {
          printf("I found %d in %d\n\n", key, middleIndex);
          break;
        }
        else if(key<array[middleIndex])
        {
            topIndex = middleIndex-1;
            middleIndex = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2;
            printf("Middle Index: %d , Top Index: %d , Bottom Index: %d\n\n", middleIndex, topIndex, bottomIndex);

        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: suggestion: a generic approach, `int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);`

Comment: need else case (`key>array[middleIndex]`) , also use `bsearch`.

Comment: I find it best to start with `topIndex = n`, that is, `topIndex` is never a valid index, and finish when `topIndex - bottomIndex == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your are on your way.

```
else if(key<array[middleIndex])
{
    topIndex = middleIndex-1;
    middleIndex = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2;
    printf("Middle Index: %d , Top Index: %d , Bottom Index: %d\n\n", middleIndex, topIndex, bottomIndex);

}
```

This section handles the case where your key is smaller then the middle position in the array. Now handle the other case:

```
else if(key>array[middleIndex])
{
    bottomIndex = middleIndex;
    middleIndex = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2;
    printf("Middle Index: %d , Top Index: %d , Bottom Index: %d\n\n", middleIndex, topIndex, bottomIndex);

}
```

Comment: Oh wow pretty sad i missed that! Thank you all its working like a champ now!

Comment: @ColinRickels: Also, factor out the calculation of `middleIndex`.  Do it at the top of the `while` loop, rather than once before the loop, and then in the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not moving the `bottomIndex` when the key is more than the value at `middleIndex`. A fixed version follows

```
while (bottomIndex <= topIndex)
{
  if (key == array[middleIndex])
  {
    printf("I found %d in %d\n\n", key, middleIndex);
    break;
  }
  else if (key<array[middleIndex])
    topIndex = middleIndex - 1;
  else
    bottomIndex = middleIndex + 1; // This part was lacking

  // This code is common to both cases above
  middleIndex = (topIndex + bottomIndex) / 2;
  printf("Middle Index: %d , Top Index: %d , Bottom Index: %d\n\n", middleIndex, topIndex, bottomIndex);
}
```